# Comparing two list to prevent duplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, dictionary

I am having some problem when trying to compare two lists and if it satisfied a requirement, then add it into another list. Here is the code:

```
// Find list of substitute with highest stock level and replace the product
prodSubstitute = prodPackBLL.getProductIDWithHighestStock(categoryName);

for (int count = 0; count < prodSubstitute.Count; count++)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in tempList)
    {
        // To prevent duplication of same product and select those catories 
        // which are in current category and counting them and taking them if 
        // there are less than 1 occurrences
        if (!prodSubstitute.Any(i => i.id == pair.Key) && 
            !prodIDList.Contains(prodSubstitute[count].id) && 
            !(lstCategory.Where(x => x.Equals(categoryName))
                         .Select(x => x).Count() >= 2))
        {
            prodIDList.Add(prodSubstitute[count].id);
            lstCategory.Add(categoryName);
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is first I get the product sorted with highest stock and store into prodSubstitute. As for the tempList Dictionary, the data are those which I selected and added in which is located in another method. If it satisfied the requirements, then add them into prodIDList.

My test data are: for prodSubstitute, it returns me 1,5,4,2,3.

As for the pair.Key, they are 1,2,3. So by right, if taking into account for the if statement, the final prodIDList should be 5 and 4. But it returning me null. Why is it so?

If I removed the !prodSubstitute.Any(i => i.id == pair.Key) in If statement, it returning me 1 and 5. Is my logic went wrong? It is not supposed to add in 1 since it's already exists in tempList.

What I am trying to do is I loop thru prodSubstitute, if there is any ID matched with the pair.Key which is ID in tempList, I do not add into the prodIDList.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's because of the LINQ query I used to cause this problem? Because whenever I added it, it just keep returning null.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> listOne;
List<string> listTwo;

List<string> uniqueList = listOne.Concat(listTwo).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: But one data type is ProductPacking whereas for the tempList is <string, string> Dictionary which getting an error message: Concat contain invalid arguemtns